# How do I use regex matches with SharedPreferences List?

Tags: dart

The following regex allows for extraction of all dates (XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX) from a particular key (Key1).

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
  r'(?<=Text\("key1:\[[^\][]*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?=[^\][]*])',
);
var match = regExp.allMatches(decrypted).map((z) => z.group(0));
    
prefs.setStringList("mykey",match);
```

With this code I have in output from match

```
(2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, ..., 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02)
```

The problem is `prefs.setStringList` is a `List` and `accept` only this format ["","","",""].  How can I adapt my output to be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`allMatches`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html) returns an `Iterable`, which is not the `List` that `SharedPreferences` requires. Use the [`toList`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) method to pass the correct data type.

```dart
prefs.setStringList("mykey",match.toList());
```

Comment: Or: `var match = [for (var m in regExp.allMatches(decrypted)) m[0]];`